# Should I use selects before updates to reduce rollbacks?

Tags: mysql, performance, transactions

Let's say you have a table of items with a counter that counts how many you have of each item. With this table you want to check if you have one of item A and two of item B and decrease the counter if you do. If you don't have enough of both items neither of them will be touched.

What is the best solution for this?

### Solution 1

Start a transaction and try to update the table where the count is >= the required amount. If one of the queries does not update something, use rollback.

### Solution 2

Use select first to check if all items are there, then do as in solution 1.

### What is the best solution?

While solution 1 is the cleanest solution I'm still worried about the InnoDB rollback performance as it is not that good. Solution 1 does not use selects, so when all items does exist it is clearly the best solution.

But what if we are talking about a hundred items and a high fail ratio(does not have enough of some items)? By selecting first to check if the items exists the update will not have to run if items are missing and rollback can be skipped.

What do you think is the best solution in such a situation where you need to update a lot of stuff, but it's all or nothing, and often the result is nothing? 1, 2 or something else, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Use solution 2. Rollback is meant to be used to recover from unexpected failures, not as part of normal processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM tbl GROUP BY item_id;
```

will get you all the counts in a single statement.

Do likewise for the other statement, then either

- process the lists in your code, or
- build a complex UPDATE that uses those two SELECTs as subqueries.

Since you have not spelled out where the counters are, etc, I can't be more specific.